# Bulk Insert on Child Records

Tags: batch

I am trying to implement one scenario for my educational purpose. I have 10 `Account` records and it has a field `Country__c` and I want to create 60K child `Contact` records for each `Account` Record.

It is throwing me

> First error: Too many DML rows: 10001 error

.

Is there any efficient way I can insert 60K `Contact` records for each `Account` record?

```
global class CreateContactBatchable implements Database.Batchable<sObject> {
    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {         
        String query = 'SELECT Id,Country__c, Name FROM Account';
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }
     
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Account> accList) {  
        for(integer i = 0; i<6;i++) { 
            List<Contact> contactInsertList = new List<Contact>();
            for(integer j = 0; j<10000;j++) {
                Contact c = new Contact();
                c.LastName = 'Contact'+j;
                c.FirstName = 'Test';
                c.Country__c = accList[0].Country__c;
                c.AccountId = accList[0].Id;
                contactInsertList.add(c); 
            }
            system.debug('DEBUG : contactInsertList : '+ contactInsertList.size());
            insert contactInsertList;
            contactInsertList.clear();
            
        }
         
    }   
     
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
        // execute any post-processing operations like sending email
    }
}
```

I am executing the batch here

```
CreateContactBatchable batchable = new CreateContactBatchable();
database.executeBatch(batchable, 1);
```

Comment: For minimum rework, remove the outer loop i = 0 to 5, ensure the batch chunk size is 1 and simply manually run the batch 6 times.

Comment: Another option would to use Bulk API 2.0 injest jobs. Following has been stated [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_bulk_v2.meta/api_bulk_v2/how_requests_are_processed.htm): `While processing ingest jobs, Salesforce Bulk API 2.0 automatically divides your job’s data into multiple batches to improve performance. Salesforce creates a separate batch for every 10,000 records in your job data, up to a daily maximum of 150,000,000 records.`, But you will need a write a different code and ensure you are inserting or upserting child records grouped by account.

Comment: @Phill W : I ended up running the batch job 6 times and yes I removed the first for loop. The main reason behind the question was to understand if there are other ways to solve this problem and I am not missing anything. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Arut : I will definitely have a look into the BULL API 2.0. Thank you!